# convert Google Docs to Docx using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, ms-word, google-api, google-drive-api

GoogleDoc is created and it logs changes, however, when i convert, i get a blank document docx. What am I doing wrong?

```
var doc_id = DocumentApp.create('Sample Document').getId();
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(doc_id);
var body = doc.getBody();
var rowsData = [['Plants', 'Animals'], ['Ficus', 'Goat'], ['Basil', 'Cat']];
body.insertParagraph(0,'test');
table = body.appendTable(rowsData);
var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId);
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=' + fileId + '&exportFormat=docx';
var options = {
headers: {
  Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
},
    muteHttpExceptions: true
}
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var doc = response.getBlob();
DriveApp.createFile(doc).setName(file.title);
```

Comment: it was in doc.saveAndClose();

Comment: you should add an answer if you found your mistake

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved! it was in doc.save And Close();